# function not working with using window.location.href

Tags: javascript, function, href

The function `html2pdf(element)` (generates a pdf of the page) works fine. After executing the function, i want to direct to an other page. In my case adding `window.location.href[...]` the page is just redirecting to the next page but the function `html2pdf` is not working anymore.

```
<script>
  $(function() {});
  function printPDF() {
    var element = document.getElementById("element-to-print");
    var opt = {
      margin: 1,
      filename: "EFS10Laptop.pdf",
      image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 1.98 },
      html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
      jsPDF: { unit: "in", format: "letter", orientation: "portrait" }
    };

    // New Promise-based usage:
    //html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).save();
    html2pdf(element);
    window.location.href = "index.php";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: add  return false; after window.location.href = "index.php";

Comment: I think html2pdf return promise .. Therefore it is not blocking at function call and move to next line without completing the task.

Comment: @kish Now it is executing the function but not redirect to index.php

Answer (score 0):

Ankur was right - `html2pdf`, either used with or without its promise based API, is asynchronous in nature, so it won't stop your code from continuing while it is processing the request, and since setting `window.location.href` is near instantaneous, the redirect is reached before html2pdf has a chance to complete.

Because `html2pdf` has the promise based API, this is very easy to avoid - simply wait until the save promise resolves to redirect, like so:

```
html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).save().then(()=>{
    window.location.href = "index.php";
});
```

Note that this still redirects the user while the save dialog is still open. I don't see a promise listed for when this is closed in [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.0) (probably because the JS side does not know about it), but it doesn't prevent html2pdf from working since the generation of the file blob occurs before the page redirects.